# "<result column> expected, got 'end'" error when using FTS tokenizer

Tags: java, android, sqlite, intellij-idea, full-text-search

I am using SQLite with the FTS tokenizer to tokenize a sentence in an Android application in Java.

Table:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tokenizer USING fts3tokenize(icu, en);
```

Tokenize code:

```
final Cursor tokenizerCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT token, start, end" +
    " FROM tokenizer" +
    " WHERE input=?;", new String[]{sentence});
```

`sentence` is the sentence to tokenize. Android Studio displays an error on `end` :

> "*<result column> expected, got 'end'*"

`start` and `end` are start and end positions of the token. This code compiles and works, but I get the error regardless. How to remove this error?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get rid of this error is to set 'Generic SQL' dialect for the file.
I've created [issue on our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-13576), please follow and vote to get noticed on any updates.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass this error, add `` around the "end".

Like this:

```
final Cursor tokenizerCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT token, start, `end`" +
                " FROM tokenizer" +
                " WHERE input=?;", new String[]{sentence});
```